# hierarchical database in python Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, algorithm, hierarchical-data

I need your help, please.

How can a python mysql hierarchical database be made with a limited number of levels (9 levels)?

Please tell me the algorithm, I have been tormented with this for a long time, but it does not work out as expected

Or, if possible, tell me please analogues of this situation in python

Comment: This kind of question is usually tagged [tag:hierarchical-data] on Stack Overflow. You can probably find good answers by following that tag. I wrote an answer that got a lot of upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/20860

Comment: MySQL 8.x includes recursive CTEs that can walk hierarchies. Your question is, however, quite vague. Please ask a more specific question.

Comment: @The Impaler See, there is a referral system. It has 9 levels. Each level receives a certain percentage. Somehow you need to recreate it in some kind of database, in mysql, if possible, it is preferable.